# Are 'active' and 'staging' required in config_directories?

Tags: 8, configuration

Is it OK to delete the 'active' and 'staging' entries automatically created in settings.php? I don't plan on using them, but it's not clear to me whether some process might expect them to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, D8 will fail with the following exception, if you delete the *active* element from the array.

> Exception: The configuration directory type *active* does not exist. in config_get_config_directory() (line 177 of core/includes/bootstrap.inc).

However, it doesn't seem to mind if you remove the `staging` entry. It's worth noting that `drush` 7 documentation says that the `staging` entry will be used by default when executing commands like `config-export` (drush 8, currently presents a nice menu listing all the `config_directories` instead of defaulting; but it's still in beta so the behavior may change).

Answer (score 1):

The [default.settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/8) file contains the following comment:

> The staging directory is used for configuration imports; the active directory is not used by default, since the default storage for active configuration is the database rather than the file system (this can be changed; see "Active configuration settings" below).

In short:

- The *staging* directory is used only when importing configuration from the UI
- The *active* directory is not used by default from Drupal 8, which saves the configuration data in the database, like Drupal 7 did with the persistent variables

In both the cases, I would expect Drupal to correctly handle the case the global `$config_directories` is not set.

Comment: Hard to miss those paragraphs in settings.php, but it's worth noting that they reference "CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY" and not "active"; so something's out of date. Importing and exporting is arbitrary to any named directory in that array via drush 7 or 8 (haven't tried the GUI). But in spite of the apparent indifference, (for example) CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY appears 26 times in 15 separate files. I don't really have the chops to wade thru all the code and figure out  whether they are critical.

Comment: See also https://www.drupal.org/node/2487592 which is an attempt at not shipping with the active directory.